# How to combine 3 SQL queries in to 1?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have products stored over 3 tables and product prices stored over 3 tables. At the moment I run each SQL query and then manually merge the data together in Microsoft Excel but is it possible to merge these queries so that I can get all results in one hit?

I was thinking about just using 3 sub queries but I'm not sure whether that is the correct way to do it or not.

### 1. Query

```
SELECT
  kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
  lzr_daten.LZR_BEZ AS "Product Name",
  lzr_przu.LZR_PR AS "Price"
FROM kust_adr,
     lzr_daten,
     lzr_przu
WHERE lzr_przu.LZR_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
AND lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR =
lzr_przu.LZR_IDNR
AND (lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR IN (85)
AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
```

### 2. Query

```
SELECT
  kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
  glas_daten_basis.GL_BEZ AS
  "Product Name",
  os_przu.ZUM2 AS "Price"
FROM glas_daten_basis,
     kust_adr,
     os_przu
WHERE os_przu.KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
AND glas_daten_basis.IDNR = os_przu.IDNR
AND (glas_daten_basis.IDNR IN (4, 104, 9, 109, 309, 311)
AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART =
0)
```

### 3. Query

```
SELECT
  kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
  gas_daten.GAS_BEZ AS "Product Name",
  gas_przu.GAS_MIN_M2 AS "Price"
FROM kust_adr,
     gas_daten,
     gas_przu
WHERE gas_przu.GAS_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
AND gas_daten.GAS_IDNR =
gas_przu.GAS_IDNR
AND (kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` them together?

Comment: if all three query column has same datatype then you can union all together .

Comment: if they aren't of the same datatype, you can to_char( ... ) every column and then use UNION or UNION ALL, depending on how to merge (without or with duplicate rows).

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 3):

UNION removes duplicate rows:

```
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       lzr_daten.LZR_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       lzr_przu.LZR_PR AS "Price"
  FROM kust_adr, lzr_daten, lzr_przu
 WHERE     lzr_przu.LZR_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
       AND lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR = lzr_przu.LZR_IDNR
       AND (lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR IN (85) AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
UNION
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       glas_daten_basis.GL_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       os_przu.ZUM2 AS "Price"
  FROM glas_daten_basis, kust_adr, os_przu
 WHERE os_przu.KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR AND glas_daten_basis.IDNR = os_przu.IDNR
       AND (glas_daten_basis.IDNR IN (4, 104, 9, 109, 309, 311)
            AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
UNION
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       gas_daten.GAS_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       gas_przu.GAS_MIN_M2 AS "Price"
  FROM kust_adr, gas_daten, gas_przu
 WHERE     gas_przu.GAS_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
       AND gas_daten.GAS_IDNR = gas_przu.GAS_IDNR
       AND (kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0);
```

UNION ALL does not remove duplicate rows:

```
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       lzr_daten.LZR_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       lzr_przu.LZR_PR AS "Price"
  FROM kust_adr, lzr_daten, lzr_przu
 WHERE     lzr_przu.LZR_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
       AND lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR = lzr_przu.LZR_IDNR
       AND (lzr_daten.LZR_IDNR IN (85) AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       glas_daten_basis.GL_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       os_przu.ZUM2 AS "Price"
  FROM glas_daten_basis, kust_adr, os_przu
 WHERE os_przu.KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR AND glas_daten_basis.IDNR = os_przu.IDNR
       AND (glas_daten_basis.IDNR IN (4, 104, 9, 109, 309, 311)
            AND kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT kust_adr.KU_NAME AS "Customer Name",
       gas_daten.GAS_BEZ AS "Product Name",
       gas_przu.GAS_MIN_M2 AS "Price"
  FROM kust_adr, gas_daten, gas_przu
 WHERE     gas_przu.GAS_KUNR = kust_adr.KU_NR
       AND gas_daten.GAS_IDNR = gas_przu.GAS_IDNR
       AND (kust_adr.KU_ADR_ART = 0);
```